# Spring MVC application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

Hi all I´m learning how to use Spring, I don´t have experience in MVC.

So I´m making a website who makes registrations, de-registrations and changes in the data of a mysql database.
The login and inserts to DB are ready but I can't make the delete registered user part.

My model:

```
 import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class StudentDelete {

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=4, max=20)
    private String userName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=4, max=8)
    private String password;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }   
}
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("student")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;
    @RequestMapping(value="/delete", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String delete(Model model) {         
            Student studentDelete = new Student();      
            model.addAttribute("studentDelete", studentDelete);
            return "delete";
        }

blablabla

        @RequestMapping(value="/delete", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String delete(@Valid @ModelAttribute("studentDelete") StudentDelete studentDelete, BindingResult result) {
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "delete";
            } else {
                boolean found = studentService.findByLogin(studentDelete.getUserName(), studentDelete.getPassword());
                if (found) {        
                    studentService.deleteByLogin(studentDelete.getUserName(), studentDelete.getPassword());
                    return "successD";
                } else {                
                    return "failureD";
                }
            }
        }
```

My Service and the implementation:

```
package com.github.elizabetht.service;

import com.github.elizabetht.model.Student;

public interface StudentService {
    Student save(Student student);
    boolean findByLogin(String userName, String password);
    boolean findByUserName(String userName);
    boolean deleteByLogin(String userName, String password);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public boolean deleteByLogin(String userName, String password) {

StudentDelete stud = studentDeleteRepository.deleteByLogin(userName, password);

    if(stud != null) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And finally The StudentDeleteRepository:

```
package com.github.elizabetht.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.github.elizabetht.model.Student;
import com.github.elizabetht.model.StudentDelete;

@Repository("studentDeleteRepository")
public interface StudentDeleteRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentDelete, Long> {

    @Query("delete s from Student s where s.userName = :userName and s.password = :password")
    StudentDelete deleteByLogin(@Param("userName") String userName, @Param("password") String password);

}
```

StudentRepository.java

```
package com.github.elizabetht.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.github.elizabetht.model.Student;

@Repository("studentRepository")
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

    @Query("select s from Student s where s.userName = :userName")
    Student findByUserName(@Param("userName") String userName);

}
```

In my delete.jsp all starts with this:

```
<form:form id="myForm" method="post"
                            class="bs-example form-horizontal" commandName="studentDelete">
```

I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.github.elizabetht.service.StudentServiceImpl.deleteByLogin(StudentServiceImpl.java:47)
```

Which is this part:

```
StudentDelete stud = studentDeleteRepository.deleteByLogin(userName, password);
```

Why it doesnt  happen with the save method?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the @Autowired annotation on the declaration of the studentDeleteRepository variable in your StudentService implementation?

Comment: Hi , yes, its in this way:  @Autowired
 private StudentRepository studentRepository;
 private StudentDeleteRepository studentDeleteRepository;

Comment: You will need the @Autowired annotation on both the studentRepository and studentDeleteRepository references.  Not just the studentRepository.

Comment: Hey man, I added the autowired but bring this : 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentDeleteRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.github.elizabetht.model.StudentDelete

Comment: I´ll keep investigating

Comment: Is there any other place where the Autowired must be?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that parameter you are passing below:

```
StudentDelete stud = studentDeleteRepository.deleteByLogin(userName, password);
```

username or password are empty.

Hence the null pointer exception.

Change your implementation to following formate:

```
public boolean deleteByLogin(String userName, String password) {

if(userName == null || password == null)
return false; // it failed essentially

StudentDelete stud = studentDeleteRepository.deleteByLogin(userName, password);

    if(stud != null) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: userName and password does have a value man, I think my problem is related with the execution of the controller-servlet 

Hibernate: 
    select
        student0_.id as id0_,
        student0_.dateOfBirth as dateOfBi2_0_,
        student0_.emailAddress as emailAdd3_0_,
        student0_.firstName as firstName0_,
        student0_.lastName as lastName0_,
        student0_.password as password0_,
        student0_.userName as userName0_ 
    from
        student student0_ 
    where
        student0_.userName=?

Brings the StudentRepository instead of the StudentDeleteRepository don´t know why

Comment: What do you mean brings the StudentRepository instead of the StudentDeleteRepository? Can you show the code for StudentRepository

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by brings the StudentRepository instead of StudentDeleteRepository? Remember if it thew and exception at deleteByLogin you won't see a hibernate query displayed. Have you tried adding that code i wrote in and see how it behaves?

Comment: It was a missunderstanding I was reading wrong the log. I solve the issue with Autowired and Placing another controller with transaction and autowired in another java class StudentDeleteService. I have a sintax errError creating bean with name 'studentDeleteRepository': QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: from near line 1, column 10 [delete s from com.github.elizabetht.model.Student s where s.userName = :userName and s.password = :password]

Comment: Fair enough, just remember null pointer exceptions occur when you are trying to process something but not actually passing data. If you think about it that way and follow basic logic you will come to root cause problem always. Hope the answer helped guide in right direction.

Comment: Yeah kind of man, the real problem is to build correctly the bean to delete the data .... I create another question for the syntax thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823230/spring-mvc-application-part2-sintax-error

Answer (score 1):

I think the error you specified in the comments:

> Not a managed type: class com.github.elizabetht.model.StudentDelete

is because you are missing the JPA @Entity annotation on your model class:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table("student")
public class StudentDelete {

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=4, max=20)
    private String userName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=4, max=8)
    private String password;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }   
}
```

Comment: yeah I solved that time ago. I want now use part of this application to a project, but got an error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774828/spring-mvc-with-jdbc-table-is-not-mapped