# Spring MVC Application syntax error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, orm

I have this question:

[Spring MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820342/spring-mvc-application/31821138?noredirect=1#comment51570131_31821138)

I solved with some new code, making *StudentDeleteRepository.java* and *StudentDeleteRepositoryImpl.java* and adding the tags as a user suggested:

```
@Autowired
private StudentDeleteRepository studentDeleteRepository;


@Transactional
public Student delete(Student student) {
    return studentDeleteRepository.save(student);
}
```

*StudentDeleteRepository.java* gives the error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentDeleteController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.github.elizabetht.service.StudentDeleteService com.github.elizabetht.controller.StudentDeleteController.studentDeleteService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentDeleteService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.github.elizabetht.repository.StudentDeleteRepository com.github.elizabetht.service.StudentDeleteServiceImpl.studentDeleteRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentDeleteRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: from near line 1, column 10 [delete s from com.github.elizabetht.model.Student s where s.userName = :userName and s.password = :password]

Here is the class *StudentDeleteRepositoryImpl.java*:

```
package com.github.elizabetht.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.github.elizabetht.model.Student;

@Repository("studentDeleteRepository")
public interface StudentDeleteRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

    @Query("delete s from Student s where s.userName = :userName and s.password = :password")
    Student deleteByLogin(@Param("userName") String userName, @Param("password") String password);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from Student s where s.userName = ?1 and s.password = ?2
```

Comment: Hi man, mmm brings another error:
FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract com.github.elizabetht.model.Student com.github.elizabetht.repository.StudentDeleteRepository.deleteByLogin(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) but parameter 'userName' not found in annotated query 'delete from Student s where s.userName = ?1 and s.password = ?2'!

Comment: Can you try to remove 'Param' annotation?

Comment: Yeah it helps my app starts the bean was correctly created but doesn´t execute when I click the delete button brings the error

Comment: :       Estado HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [delete from com.github.elizabetht.model.Student s where s.userName = ?1 and s.password = ?2]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [delete from..... ?2]

Comment: delete user part completed... for those who has that error:

 //@Modifying  
    //@Query("delete from Student s where s.userName = :userName and s.password = :password")
 @Transactional
    int deleteByLogin(@Param("userName") String userName, //@Param("password") String password);

that solves the thing

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain _how_ it solves the problem without introducing others and _why_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

The query you are using in your code is of Hibernate query, not JPA query.
See below how to write JPA query in `where` conditions.

`@Param` annotation is used in the Service declaration or implementation, not in the JPA repository implementation. So change it accordingly.

```
@Query("delete s from Student s where s.userName = ?1 and s.password = ?2")
Student deleteByLogin(String userName, String password);
```