# Spring MVC with jdbc "table is not mapped"

Tags: mysql, spring, model-view-controller

So I´m trying to make an application with all http request get, put, post, delete.I'm making first a login with mysql and spring 3. So here I got this:

login.jsp:

```
                    <form:form id="myForm" method="post"
                        class="bs-example form-horizontal" commandName="UsersLogin">
```

signup.jsp

```
<form:form id="myForm" method="post"
                        class="bs-example form-horizontal" commandName="Users">
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence} {http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence_2_0.xsd}"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="punit">
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Here is my jpaContext.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.portuzona.repository" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/portuzona?autoReconnect=true&amp;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="1234" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

com.portuzona.model

Users model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=4, max=20)
    private String userName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=4, max=8)
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty
    private String status;


    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String emailAddress;


    @NotNull
    @Past
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }



    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }   
}
```

USersLogin model:

```
public class UsersLogin {

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=4, max=20)
    private String userName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=4, max=8)
    private String password;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }   
}
```

com.portuzona.service

```
public interface UsersService {
    Users save(Users users);
    boolean findByLogin(String userName, String password);
    boolean findByUserName(String userName);

}
```

Implementation:

```
@Service("UsersService")
public class UsersServiceImpl implements UsersService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Users save(Users users) {
        return usersRepository.save(users);
    }

    public boolean findByLogin(String userName, String password) {  
        Users stud = usersRepository.findByUserName(userName);

        if(stud != null && stud.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            return true;
        } 

        return false;       
    }

    public boolean findByUserName(String userName) {
        Users use = usersRepository.findByUserName(userName);

        if(use != null) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

com.portuzona.repository

```
@Repository("UsersRepository")
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT s FROM users s WHERE s.userName = :userName")
    Users findByUserName(@Param("userName") String userName);

}
```

com.portuzona.controller

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("users")
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private UsersService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/signup", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signup(Model model) {
        Users users = new Users();      
        model.addAttribute("users", users);     
        return "signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/signup", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String signup(@Valid @ModelAttribute("users") Users users, BindingResult result, Model model) {      
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "signup";
        } else if(userService.findByUserName(users.getUserName())) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "User Name exists. Try another user name");
            return "signup";
        } else {
            userService.save(users);
            model.addAttribute("message", "Saved users details");
            return "redirect:login.html";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model) {          
        UsersLogin usersLogin = new UsersLogin();       
        model.addAttribute("UsersLogin", usersLogin);
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@Valid @ModelAttribute("UsersLogin") UsersLogin usersLogin, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "login";
        } else {
            boolean found = userService.findByLogin(usersLogin.getUserName(), usersLogin.getPassword());
            if (found) {                
                return "success";
            } else {                
                return "failure";
            }
        }

    }



}
```

I got this error when trying to access to /login or /signup where I have my .jsp with my forms:

```
sep 24, 2015 11:14:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet usersHibernateServlet
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: users is not mapped [SELECT s FROM users s WHERE s.userName = :userName]
```

I have been with this for two days, looking for answers here but no kind of good results from my side... just gives me the same error, any idea?

Comment: Learn JPQL. JPQL is not SQL. It doesn't use table and column names, but entities and their fields. You don't have any JPA entity named "users". It's named "Users" (and should really, really be named "User": an instance of Users represents ONE user, not several, so it should be singular).

Comment: entity users is created... anyway I change everything to User and have the same error

Comment: So, what's your query now? And what's the error message you get?

Comment: "SELECT s FROM user s WHERE s.userName = :userName"

Comment: So you did the exact same mistake. The entity is not named "user". It's named "User".

Comment: mmm interesting... so I get the entity not the table name ok...  cool error resolved. Thanks!